# Help adding a live device to an Xcode 4 project

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

Argggh, I have built a couple Apps in Xcode 4 but I cannot remember/find how to add my live device to my schemes drop down.  I have the simulator options, but in the newest project I created I do not have my iphone listed.

Can anyone tell me what I forgot to do??

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

EDIT:  Any new project I create does not create anything for my Device, however, some of the sample apps I open have my device listed... there are a lot of developers out there... hopefully someone has had this issue and can shed some light on what I am not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem.  I forgot that my device is ios 4.2, so to make it work in xCode, I need to change the deployment target to the correct ios version and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to do anything special, just plug the device in. After about 30 seconds or so it will show up as an option in your target list.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but this time it is not showing up... I have plugged and unplugged my device many times and no luck!

Comment: Now that I think back...you may have to open up Organizer and "enable for development"

Comment: Yes it shows up in iTunes and if I open ANY sample project it automagically appears, but the newest project I created it does not show up.